# Symfony 3 ORM creates new entity record after persist

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, persist

i'm trying to create a new record in Team entity with existing user as owner from User's Entity but after using persist it creates a new user rather than attaching it to record.

```
    public function createTeam(Request $request)
    {
        $teamForm = $this->createForm(TeamType::class);

        $teamForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($teamForm->isSubmitted() && $teamForm->isValid()) {

            $user = $this->getUser();
            $team = $teamForm->getData();

            $team->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime())
                 ->setCreator($user);

            $this->em->persist($team);
    //dd($team);
            $this->em->flush();

        }
```

ORM:

```
        /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SteamUser", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="steam_user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $creator;
```

Here is what dump record looks like:

```
    TeamController.php on line 52:
Team {#591 ▼
  -id: null
  -creator: SteamUser {#238 ▼
    -id: 1
    -roles: array:1 [▶]
    -nickName: "steamuser"
    -userName: "76561192288153971"
    -password: "LrC8fFLuIdPqAiDHDATiheRaIBk="
    -avatar: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9e/9e8567cc32383f28df41da7fbca7e8afd47f8516.jpg"
    -teams: PersistentCollection {#290 ▶}
  }
  -name: "dasdasdasdas"
  -logo: null
  -teamType: 2
  -createdAt: DateTime {#594 ▶}
  -roster: ArrayCollection {#571 ▶}
}
```

as you can see user before persist has ID and is recognized but after persist it creates a new user in database.

Please give some good advices.

Comment: Are there any events fired after this persist or request?

Comment: It creates new user in database with same id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user object from entity so that doctrine can relate your team entity to this user right now you are getting user object from i guess security context which is not a doctrine object that is why new user is created.

> this should be changed as below `$user = $this->getUser();`

```
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\SteamUser')
           ->find($this->getUser()->getId());
```